# How do I change the TIMESTAMPDIFF date format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, date-format, sql-timestamp, timestampdiff

I'm using the value of one date table, minus the other date table to create a total time date table.
However, I don't like the format.

```
CONCAT(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,TIME_END,TIME_START), 'd',
        MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,TIME_END,TIME_START), 24), 'h',
        MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,TIME_END,TIME_START), 60), 'm'
      ) AS Total_Times
```

Results appear like this:

- 0d0h-48m
- -2d-1h-7m
- 0d0h-33m
- 0d0h0m
- -1d-21h-47m

It seems that if the number is higher than zero, it'll add a hyphen next to it, otherwise it'll group whatever is next to it without a space. How can I get it to create a space between zero's and and remove hyphens to appear like this:

- 0d 0h 48m
- 2d 1h 7m
- 0d 0h 33m
- 0d 0h 0m
- 1d 21h 47m

Note, in the actual date columns (TIME_END,TIME_START) their values are written like 2020-11-02 15:32:28.

Comment: You get a minus sign before negative numbers. That's pretty much the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the real issue here is that sometimes you are placing `TIME_START` and `TIME_END` in the wrong positions.  If you want to diff an earlier start time against a later end time, then the former should appear *before* the latter in the call to `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.  Use this version:

```sql
CONCAT(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, TIME_START, TIME_END), 'd ',
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, TIME_START, TIME_END), 24), 'h ',
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, TIME_START, TIME_END), 60), 'm'
) AS Total_Times
```

To comment further on your current output, e.g.

```
-2d-1h-7m
```

The dashes you see here are actually *minus* signs, not dashes.  You should have swapped the order of `TIME_START` and `TIME_END` to get positive numbers.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. Thank you very much for taking the time to change it for me and explaining why it was displaying like that!